# Issue creating an email with tables in body

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am looking for a way to export the results of multiple queries (2-3) and export the results into an email. I know something similar can be done with PHP and CRON, but everything I could find only does one query result per email, I am looking to send multiple query results in one email.

The result should be formatted as a table in an email preferably and not an attached excel.

Can something like this be accomplished?

**Additional Details:**

I am using a mySQL database the query that I would like the results from is a very simple select query like the following:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, sign_date, employee_id FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()
```

And a second query like:

```
SELECT employee_id, job_title, address FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()
```

I would like the results of both of these queries to be sent out in an email where one table is listed under the other as so:

[Example of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQMyq.png)

I currently have the following PHP script that exports two arrays, how can I take this and format it as the tables above and have them sent in an email at a certain time.

```
<?php

$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'dbname';
$userdb = 'username';
$passdb = 'password';
$charset = 'utf8'; 

    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb;dbname=$namedb;charset=$charset", $userdb, $passdb, $options);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT first_name, last_name, sign_date, employee_id FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()');
    $stmt->execute([]);

    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT employee_id, job_title, address FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()');
    $stmt2->execute([]);

  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $row2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo json_encode($row);
  echo json_encode($row2);

?>
```

**I also understand the email can be created in PHP as the following, but how can the arrays form the 2 tables and present them in the body? :**

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";


// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: So, loop over the results, and assemble the according HTML code in a string variable …? You should at least have some attempt to show here. If not, then you should perhaps go work through a beginner’s tutorial that explains how to work with database query results first.

Comment: Why do you have two select statements for a query that requests data from the same table with the same parameter?

Comment: I would like to split the data into two tables

Comment: @nbk Can you show how something like this can be done?

Comment: @BradSlen  The first step would be to create a static/fixed HTML representation of the table that you want to create.  Are you able to do that? Do you have basic HTML knowledge?  If you are able to do that, then you start to replace the repeated parts with a loop and PHP variables.  Make an attempt and see how far you get.

Comment: Something like this if you have two tables SELECT t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t1.sign_date, t1.employee_id, t2.job_title, t2.addres
FROM Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 ON t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id 
WHERE t1.sign_date = NOW()